# string BUG in c project for school

Tags: c, eclipse, debugging, gcc, struct

I need to program a small airport management system for a school project and I have a terrible bug in my code.

As soon as I initialize the airportManager with more than one airport, all the IATA codes in the airports array get the name of the last airport that was input.

I have tried debugging it a lot of time but without any success. Everything is fine until I print the IATA code or use it. I will be glad for any help.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define TEMP_STR_LEN 255
#define IATA_SIZE 3

// Airport struct:
struct Airport
{
    char name[TEMP_STR_LEN];
    char country[TEMP_STR_LEN];
    char iata[IATA_SIZE];
} typedef airport;

// Airport functions:
int compareAirports(airport const *airport1, airport const *airport2)
{
    if (strcmp(airport1->iata, airport2->iata) != 0)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}

int compareIataCode(airport *airport1, char const *iata)
{
    if (strcmp(airport1->iata, iata) != 0)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}

void NameArrange(char *name)
{
    char tmpString[255];
    tmpString[0] = '\0';
    char *token = strtok(name, " ");
    int i, place = 0, strTotalLen = 0, lastTokenLen = 0;

    while (token != NULL)
    {
        place++;

        if (strlen(token) % 2 == 0)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < strlen(token) - 1; i++)
            {
                if (token[i] >= 'a' && token[i] <= 'z')
                {
                    token[i] -= 32; // by ascii table
                }
                if ((token[i + 1] >= 'A' && token[i + 1] <= 'Z'))
                    token[i + 1] += 32; // by ascii table
                i++;
            }
        }
        else if (token[0] >= 'a' && token[0] <= 'z')
            token[0] -= 32;

        if (place != 1)
            strcat(tmpString, "  ");

        strncat(tmpString, token, strlen(token));
        strTotalLen += strlen(token);
        lastTokenLen = strlen(token);
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    strTotalLen += (place - 1) * 2;
    if (lastTokenLen % 2 != 0)
        tmpString[strTotalLen - lastTokenLen] += 32;
    strcpy(name, tmpString);
}

// ***Airport manager struct***
struct AirportManager
{
    int airportsCount;
    airport *airportArr;
} typedef airportMan;

// airportManager functions
void addAirport(airportMan *airportManager,  airport *airportToAdd)
{
    airportManager->airportArr = (airport *) realloc(airportManager->airportArr, (airportManager->airportsCount + 1) * (sizeof(airport)));
    strcpy(airportManager->airportArr[airportManager->airportsCount].name, airportToAdd->name);
    strcpy(airportManager->airportArr[airportManager->airportsCount].country, airportToAdd->country);
    strcpy(airportManager->airportArr[airportManager->airportsCount].iata, airportToAdd->iata);
    airportManager->airportsCount++;
    printf(" BUG!!! %s\n", airportManager->airportArr[0].iata);
}

bool airportFind(airportMan *airportManager, char  *iataCode)
{
    int i;
    printf("%s", airportManager->airportArr[0].iata );
    char airportIata[IATA_SIZE];
    char airportIata2[IATA_SIZE];
    strcpy(airportIata, iataCode);
    strcpy(airportIata2, airportManager->airportArr[0].iata);
    if (strcmp(airportIata, airportIata2) == 0)
        return true;
// for (i = 1; i < airportManager->airportsCount; i++) {

// printf("%s",airportManager->airportArr[0].iata );

// return true;
// }
    puts("Airport not found");
    return false;
}

bool checkDuplicatedIata(const airportMan *airportManger, const char *iata)
{
    // checks if there is already airport with the same iata code as the input
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < airportManger->airportsCount; i++)
    {
        if (compareIataCode(&(airportManger->airportArr[i]), iata))
        {
            puts("This IATA code is already exists, please try again");
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

bool checkIataSize(const char *iata)
{
    if (strlen(iata) != IATA_SIZE)
    {
        puts("The IATA code must be 3 letters");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

bool checkIataLetters(const char *iata)
{
    // checks if all the letters in a given iata code are all capital
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(iata); i++)
    {
        if (iata[i] >= 'a' && iata[i] <= 'z')
        {
            puts("The IATA code must be in capital letters");
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

bool checkIataOk(const char *iata, const airportMan *airportManager)
{
    if (checkDuplicatedIata(airportManager, iata) == false
        && checkIataSize(iata) && checkIataLetters(iata))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

airport *initAirport(airportMan *airportManager)
{
    // asks the user to input an airport
    airport *iniAirport;

    iniAirport = (airport *) malloc(sizeof(airport));
    char tmpStr[TEMP_STR_LEN];
    char *ptr;
    bool iataOk = false;
    printf("please enter airport details (press enter to confirm):\nName:");
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets(tmpStr, 255, stdin);
    if ((ptr = strchr(tmpStr, '\n')) != NULL)
        *ptr = '\0';
    strcpy(iniAirport->name, tmpStr);
    NameArrange(iniAirport->name);
    printf("Country:");
    fgets(iniAirport->country, 255, stdin);
    if ((ptr = strchr(iniAirport->country, '\n')) != NULL)
        *ptr = '\0';
    while (!iataOk)
    {
        printf("IATA code:");
        fgets(iniAirport->iata, TEMP_STR_LEN, stdin);
        fflush(stdin);
        if ((ptr = strchr(iniAirport->iata, '\n')) != NULL)
            *ptr = '\0';
        iataOk = checkIataOk(iniAirport->iata, airportManager);
    }
    return iniAirport;
}

airportMan *initAirportManager()
{
    airportMan *airportManager = (airportMan *) malloc(sizeof(airportMan));
    if (airportManager == NULL)
        return NULL;
    airportManager->airportsCount = 0;

    int airportsCount = 0, i = 0;
    puts("Please enter how much airports you want to add");
    scanf("%d", &airportsCount);
    getchar();
    for (i = 0; i < airportsCount; i++)
    {
        airport *airport = initAirport(airportManager);
        addAirport(airportManager, airport);
    }
    return airportManager;
}

// ****Struct date*******

struct Date
{
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
} typedef date_t;

bool checkDateFormat(char *dateString)
{
    char tmpString[TEMP_STR_LEN] = "";
    strcpy(tmpString, dateString);

    char *token = strtok(tmpString, "/");

    if (strlen(token) == 2)
    {
        token = strtok(NULL, "/");
        if (strlen(token) == 2)
        {
            token = strtok(NULL, "/");
            if (strlen(token) == 4)
                return true;
            puts("Please enter the date in the correct format");
            return false;
        }
        puts("Please enter the date in the correct format");
        return false;
    }
    puts("Please enter the date in the correct format");
    return false;
}

bool checkDate(date_t *date)
{
    int daysArr[12] = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };
    if (date->month > 0 && date->month <= 12)
    {
        if (date->day > 0 && date->day <= daysArr[date->month - 1])
        {
            if (date->year >= 2020)
                return true;
            puts("Invalid year, please try again");
            return false;
        }
        puts("Invalid day, please try again");
        return false;
    }
    puts("Invalid month, please try again");
    return false;
}

date_t *initDate()
{
    date_t *date;
    char tmpDateString[TEMP_STR_LEN];
    char *ptr;
    bool checkFormat = false;
    bool checkValid = false;
    date = (date_t *) malloc(sizeof(date_t));
    while ((!checkFormat) || (!checkValid))
    {
        puts("Please enter date in the following format: dd/mm/yyyy ");
        fgets(tmpDateString, TEMP_STR_LEN, stdin);
        if ((ptr = strchr(tmpDateString, '\n')) != NULL)
            *ptr = '\0';
        checkFormat = checkDateFormat(tmpDateString);
        char *token = strtok(tmpDateString, "/");
        date->day = atoi(token);
        token = strtok(NULL, "/");
        date->month = atoi(token);
        token = strtok(NULL, "/");
        date->year = atoi(token);
        checkValid = checkDate(date);
    }
    return date;
}

// ***Flight struct***

struct Flight
{
    char departureAirport[TEMP_STR_LEN];
    char arrivalAirport[TEMP_STR_LEN];
    int takeofTime;
    date_t *date;
} typedef flight_f;

// ***flight functions
bool checkTakeOffTime(const flight_f *flight)
{
    if ((flight->takeofTime >= 0 && flight->takeofTime <= 23))
        return true;
    puts("Invalid time");
    return false;
}

bool compareFlightIata(const char *srcIata, const char *destIata)
{
    return strcmp(srcIata, destIata) == 0;
}

bool compareFlightPath(const char *srcIata, const char *destIata)
{
    if (compareFlightIata(srcIata, destIata))
    {
        puts("Flight must have different destination and source airports  ");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

flight_f *initFlight(airportMan *airportManager)
{
    flight_f *flight;
    char *ptr;
    bool checkIata = false;
    bool takeoffCheck = false;
    bool airportExists = false;
    flight = (flight_f *) malloc(sizeof(flight_f));
    puts("Please enter flight details ");
    while (!checkIata || !airportExists)
    {
        puts("\nSrc airport:");
        fgets(flight->departureAirport, TEMP_STR_LEN, stdin);
        if ((ptr = strchr(flight->departureAirport, '\n')) != NULL)
            *ptr = '\0';
        checkIata = (checkIataSize(flight->departureAirport)
                     && checkIataLetters(flight->departureAirport));
        if (checkIata)
            airportExists = airportFind(airportManager, flight->departureAirport);
    }
    checkIata = false;
    airportExists = false;
    while (!checkIata || !airportExists)
    {
        puts("\nDec airport:");
        fgets(flight->arrivalAirport, TEMP_STR_LEN, stdin);
        if ((ptr = strchr(flight->arrivalAirport, '\n')) != NULL)
            *ptr = '\0';
        checkIata = (checkIataSize(flight->arrivalAirport)
                     && checkIataLetters(flight->arrivalAirport)
                     && compareFlightPath(flight->departureAirport,
                                          flight->arrivalAirport));
        if (checkIata)
            airportExists = airportFind(airportManager, flight->arrivalAirport);
    }
    while (!takeoffCheck)
    {
        puts("\nTakeoff time: ");
        scanf("%d", &flight->takeofTime);
        getchar();
        takeoffCheck = checkTakeOffTime(flight);
    }
    flight->date = initDate();
    return flight;
}

bool checkFlightPath(flight_f flight, char const *departureFrom,
                     char const *arrivingTo)
{
    if (strcmp(flight.departureAirport, departureFrom) == 0
        && strcmp(flight.arrivalAirport, arrivingTo) == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

int flightPathFind(flight_f **flightsArr, char const *departureFrom,
                   char const *arrivingTo, int size)
{
    int count = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (checkFlightPath((*flightsArr)[i], departureFrom, arrivingTo))
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

// Struct airline
struct Airline
{
    char name[TEMP_STR_LEN];
    int filghtsCount;
    flight_f **flightsArr;
} typedef airline_a;

void addFlightToAirline(airline_a *airline, airportMan *airportManager)
{
    airline->flightsArr = (flight_f **) realloc(airline->flightsArr,
                                                (airline->filghtsCount + 1) * sizeof(flight_f *));
    flight_f *flightToAdd = initFlight(airportManager);
    airline->flightsArr[airline->filghtsCount] = flightToAdd;
    airline->filghtsCount++;
}

void airlineFlightsCount(airline_a *airline, char const *departureFrom,
                         char const *arrivingTo)
{
    int i;
    int count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < airline->filghtsCount; i++)
    {
        if (checkFlightPath(*(airline->flightsArr[i]), departureFrom, arrivingTo))
            count++;
    }
    printf("%s airline has %d flights in that path\n", airline->name, count);
}

airline_a *initAirline()
{
    airline_a *airline;
    airline = (airline_a *)malloc(sizeof(airline_a));
    if (airline == NULL)
        return NULL;
    char *ptr;
    puts("Please enter airline name:");
    fgets(airline->name, TEMP_STR_LEN, stdin);
    if ((ptr = strchr(airline->name, '\n')) != NULL)
        *ptr = '\0';
    airline->filghtsCount = 0;
    airline->flightsArr = NULL;
    return airline;
}

int main()
{
    airportMan *airportManager = initAirportManager();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Airport codes are 3 characters long, so you need to reserve 4 bytes for them, 3 for the letters (LHR, DIA, LAX, ...) and 1 for the null byte that marks the end of the string.

Comment: You have `struct Airport { … } typedef airport;` — that's currently legal C, but placing the storage class (`static`, `extern`, `register`, `auto` or `typedef`) other than first is an [obsolescent feature](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.11.5).  Don't do it.  Use `typedef struct Airport { … } airport;` (or, better for consistency, use `Airport` for the type name as well as the structure tag — they're in separate name spaces so you can use both `struct Airport` and `Airport` without problems).

Comment: Ideally, you should create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).
It's hard to believe this code is an MCVE.  You should make a copy of your current program and then remove parts that you don't need, testing to ensure that the problem still reproduces.  Using a good VCS (version control system) and saving every version in it will help enormously.  Having a good automatic test will help too.

Comment: Put _all_ the `typedef` definitions at the top [vs. interspersing them between functions]. If your program got large enough that you wanted to split it into multiple `.c` files, you could put the `typedef`s in a `.h` file. It's far more idiomatic that way.

Comment: Johnathan's comment about `iata` code needing 4 bytes is a good start. I downloaded your code and applied that fix. Your `BUG` message only prints index 0. Change to (e.g): `printf(" BUG!!! %s\n", mgr->airportArr[mgr->airportsCount].iata); mgr->airportsCount++;` (Note that, for brevity [to save typing and improve readability], I changed all `airportManager` symbols to `mgr`). So, now, instead of it printing the IATA code _and_ the city name jumbled together, the `BUG` message just prints the correct IATA code. So, that may be the fix for your immediate issue.

Comment: BTW, the function can be simplied a bit: `void addAirport(airportMan *mgr, airport *add) { int count = mgr->airportsCount++;  mgr->airportArr = realloc(mgr->airportArr, (count + 1) * (sizeof(airport)));  airport *arr = &mgr->airportArr[count]; *arr = *add;  printf(" BUG!!! %s\n", arr->iata); }`